# Android divide an image in multiple region for onClick events

Tags: java, android, split, onclick, imageview

In this application, I have for example an image representing the map of Germany. I want to be able to click on one specific state, for example, Bavaria and something should happen (on click function).

I can maybe place a table layout on top of the image filled whit blank images and activate the on click method only on the one covering the states, but this is probably bad coding, and I think will be poorly compatible whit other types of device, tablet or bigger/smaller screen.

Another solution can be to create two image of the map. One with different colors of the states, and another with the desired layout to show. Put the colored one as invisible on top of the second one.

XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/my_frame"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@color/background" >
 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/image_areas"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:visibility="invisible"
     android:src="@drawable/mapcolor" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:src="@drawable/mapdisplay"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java :

```
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev) {
     final int action = ev.getAction();
     // (1) 
     final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
     final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
     switch (action) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
       if (currentResource == R.drawable.mapdisplay) { 
       } 
       break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
       // Switch to a different image, depending on what color was touched.
       int touchColor = getHotspotColor (R.id.image_areas, evX, evY);
       // Switch to a different image, depending on what color was touched.
       ColorTool ct = new ColorTool ();
       int tolerance = 25;
       nextImage = R.drawable.mapdisplay;
       // (3)
       if (ct.closeMatch (Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance)) {
          // Do the action associated with the RED region
          // onClick function here ?
       } else {
         //...
       }
       break;
      } // end switch
      return true;
}
```

Color Tool :

```
public class ColorTool {
    public boolean closeMatch (int color1, int color2, int tolerance) {
        if ((int) Math.abs (Color.red (color1) - Color.red (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
        if ((int) Math.abs (Color.green (color1) - Color.green (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
        if ((int) Math.abs (Color.blue (color1) - Color.blue (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
        return true;
    } // end match
} // end class
```

As expected this is not working for me. Can someone explain to me this method or a good way to have an image "map" with multiple regions to click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of having a 2D matrix having a map of the states. There should be an initial version of the matrix which maps with different numbers for the different region based on their locations. For larger or smaller screen size, the matrix needs to be dynamic and remapped among the pixels. Let us consider the following grid as an example.

```
--------------
00111122224444
01111222222444
11122222444444
11222244444433
12222444444333
22224444444433
22255444444333
22555554443333
25555555433333
--------------
```

We can see 5 states here with their respective numbering in the matrix which follows the map. If the screen size doubles, you need to translate the values to have a larger segment and vice versa.

I was thinking of plotting such matrix which can be translated into larger or smaller dimensions based on the screen size. Now you need to set the image of the map as screen background and take an `onTouchListener` to get the pixel of the area touched to determine which area is being clicked.

This is just to give an idea of how this problem could be solved. I found one similar idea [here in the MapChart](https://mapchart.net/germany.html). Hope that helps!